# ElasticSearch - calculate ratio between aggregation buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the following terms aggregations to get views and clicks of each campaign ( by campaign_id ) :

```
"aggregations": {
"campaigns": {
        "terms": {
    "field": "campaign_id",
    "size": 10,
    "order": {
      "_term": "asc"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "actions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "action",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

This is the response I get:

```
   "aggregations": {
  "campaigns": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "someId",
           "doc_count": 12,
           "actions": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "click",
                    "doc_count": 3
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "view",
                    "doc_count": 9
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
  }
```

}

**EDIT:**
Here is an example of a document ( only the relevant parts of it..):

```
{
"_index": "action",
"_type": "click",
"_id": "AVI2XOTl8otXlszOjypT",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "timestamp": "2016-01-12T15:03:23.622743524Z",
    "action": "click",
    "campaign_id": "IypmiroC"
}}
```

I need to be able to retrieve the conversion rate of each campaign (  clicks / views ) , and I can't do it on the client side since I need to be able to sort by conversion rate.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you post one sample document?

Comment: I added one as an edit, thanks

Comment: click and view both are actions right?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the easiest way but I can change it if needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will require use of various `aggregations` and `ES 2.x`. First I am  getting all unique campaign_id with [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Then I am [filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) with `actions` and getting the [count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) of documents with that particular action. Then You need to use `pipeline aggregation` introduced in `ES 2.0`, mainly [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) to take the ratio. This is how it looks.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_campaign": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "campaign_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "click_bucket": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "action": "click"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "click_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "action"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "view_bucket": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "action": "view"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "view_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "action"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "conversion_ratio": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total_clicks": "click_bucket>click_count",
              "total_views": "view_bucket>view_count"
            },
            "script": "total_clicks/total_views"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you need to have `not_analyzed` mapping for `action` as *Click* wont match *click*.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. bonus question : how do I sort the results by the conversion_ratio ?

Comment: glad I could help, I am afraid we cant do that yet, `pipeline aggregations` are different kind of aggregations, sorting can only be performed on `Metric aggregations`.[More](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ordering-terms-aggregation-based-on-pipeline-metric/31839/2) on that. There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486) on that

Comment: Is there any other way I can do sorting based on the conversion_ratio ? I don't mind doing it even in 2 different requests

Comment: I cant see any way even with multiple queries, sorry about that, btw there is no way you can sort buckets on server side after getting the results?

Comment: I want to use pagination, so sorting can't be done on the server side but on ES only

Comment: Is it possible to sort by multiple aggregation ( not pipelined ) ? In this example to sort by the click_bucket or view_bucket. Is it possible to then take that order that was determined by one of the aggs and apply it to the other one, in a single query? Or will I need multiple queries?

Comment: sorry I am not able to help on this one, I will give it one more shot whenever I get some time, it looks difficult though.

Comment: i'm not sure why is it the solution, as it doesn't verify the the click and view came from the same ip

Answer (score 0):

As for now `7.x`, `sorting` can be achieved as follows, just a demo for reference:

- [bucket_script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html)
- [bucket_sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html)

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "mallBucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mallId",
        "size": 20,
        "min_doc_count": 3,
        "shard_size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalOrderCount": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "orderSn"
          }
        },
        "filteredCoupon": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "tags": [
                "hello",
                "cool"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "couponCount": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "orderSn"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "countRatio": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "orderCount": "totalOrderCount",
              "couponCount": "filteredCoupon>couponCount"
            },
            "script": "params.couponCount/params.orderCount"
          }
        },
        "ratio_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "countRatio": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```